# how to set schema in oracle sql developer for oracle e business suite tables

Tags: oracle, oracle-ebs

I have tried

```
set schema apps;
```

trying in Oracle e-business suite tables getting below message

> line 2: SQLPLUS Command Skipped: set schema apps

Is it executed?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood the question, it is `alter session` you're looking for, e.g.

```
alter session set current_schema = apps;
```

(presuming that schema/username really is `apps`).

Answer (score 0):

Adding one idea to Littlefoot's correct answer: To avoid typing this over and over again, you should ask your DBAs to create a logon trigger for that user, e.g. APPS_QUERY

```
create or replace trigger apps.apps_query_logon_trg
after logon on apps_query.schema
begin
  execute immediate 'alter session set current_schema=apps';
end;
/
```