# table not found issue in oracle database

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, oracle-apps

I am running below query from `sqldeveloper`.

```
select  apps.inv_project.get_pjm_locsegs('concatenated_segments') from dual;
```

then I am getting below error.

[image]

I searched in the package and table indeed exist.

```
 SELECT concatenated_segment_delimiter
        FROM apps.fnd_id_flex_structures
       WHERE id_flex_code = 'MTLL'
         AND ROWNUM = 1;
```

am i doing something wrong?

Comment: Most pobably You do not have enough privileges.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume that `SELECT` statement you posted points to line #1978 (where the error was raised).

If you can select from the table on **SQL** level, it means that you have required privileges.

But, if you aren't the owner of that table and acquired privileges on it via **role**, then such privileges won't work in named stored procedures (which is your `inv_project.get_pjm_locsegs` function, part of the package; right?).

If that's so, you should grant those privileges **directly** to user which is using the table (and that's `apps`).

Comment: thank you so much. In understoof issue now.

Answer (score 2):

This package is defined as authid current_user. It either needs to be executed as the APPS database user, or have the current_schema set to apps, presumed you have granted all required privileges to the non-apps DB user you are currently logged in with.

I saw you prefixed the call to inv_project and the query on fnd_id_flex_structures with 'apps.'. Instead of prefixing every table, better ask your DBAs to create a logon trigger to change the schema for your database account, as explained here:
[how to set schema in oracle sql developer for oracle e business suite tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61381042/how-to-set-schema-in-oracle-sql-developer-for-oracle-e-business-suite-tables/61391239#61391239)